# Automated XML (de)serialization on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, rest

What are my enterprise-level options for XML Databinding on Android?

It's possible i'm misusing the term "databinding": I'm looking for support for automatic (de)serialization of java pojos to & from XML. This is in context of communicating with REST services that do not have any client package to use.

Initial research into this problem has demonstrated, much to my surprise, that accomplishing this task on Android has many barriers:

- The Java-standard JAXB library isn't present on Android
- The Java-standard XML streaming package isn't present on Android
- Jackson XML doesn't work without XML streaming (or a suspect
  workaround)
- SimpleXML isn't JAX-RS compliant, requires pojo re-annotations, and worst: requires significant work to handle a non-trivial variety of common objects (eg; UUID, URI)

I'm quite surprised that such a common & trivial problem on other platforms leads to what feels like a dead-end.

The services I'm working with are in an alpha state, so do not have a stable domain model. Before diving into the fragile world of sax parsers, pull parsers, and/or xpath & template, what are my other options? What enterprise-friendly libraries might i have missed?

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: retrofit definitely looks worth a try. seems to have a some feature overlap with Jersey that is definitely interesting. might want to put the suggestion as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://square.github.io/retrofit

It supports xml, not just json.

It's what everybody seems to be using these days.

Comment: while this was a good suggestion, Retrofit doesn't quite solve the problem. Since it still uses SimpleXML to deserialize, Retrofit doesn't handle the common cases for unsupported objects. after all this research, it still looks like there simply isn't a solution to this otherwise trivial problem on Android.